# How can I conditionally set read only attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I have the following kendo dropdown list in my code

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(p => p.StatusID)
    .OptionLabel("Status")
    .BindTo(codes_status)
    .DataTextField(nameof(Model.StatusCode))
    .DataValueField(nameof(Model.StatusID))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:50%", @readonly = "@(userCanEditProduct)" })
    .ValuePrimitive(true)
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
 )
```

In my code I used the following code to set `readonly` property as:

```
@{
      bool userInProductUpdateRole = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Product Update");
      bool userInAdminRole = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("Admin");
       var userCanEditProject = (!userInProductUpdateRole && !userInAdminRole)
}
```

But dropdown always display as readonly.

I also tried

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(p => p.StatusID)
        .OptionLabel("Status")
        .BindTo(codes_status)
        .DataTextField(nameof(Model.StatusCode))
        .DataValueField(nameof(Model.StatusID))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:50%", @readonly = (!userInProductUpdateRole && !userInAdminRole) })
        .ValuePrimitive(true)
        .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
     )
```

Is it possible to set condition as shown above above?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the conditional logic in a Razor code block and generate an object that will contain the desired HtmlAttributes and then pass it to the .HtmlAttributes configuration of the DropDownList:

```
@{
  object myHtmlAttributes = null;
  var shouldBeReadOnly = true; // based on your conditional logic.
    if(shouldBeReadOnly) {
        myHtmlAttributes = new { style = "width:50%", @readonly = "readonly" };
    }
    else {
        myHtmlAttributes = new { style = "width:50%" };
    }
}

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("ddl")
      ...
      .HtmlAttributes(myHtmlAttributes)
)
```

[Here is an example](https://netcorerepl.telerik.com/QcuxlnvR44uCBSx237)